# Retrieve a data from a partition in SQL Servertable

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, partitioning

I'm new to `SQL Server partitioning`. I have tried a some of the tutorials and finally I got [this](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/table-partitioning-in-sql-server/) based on that created a partition but the problem is that I can't retrieve the data's based on partition like in `MYSQL` query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME  PARTITION(partitionId)
```

and also tried this query in `SQL Server`

```
SELECT $PARTITION.partition_function (partition_function_id)
```

> **EDIT:**

[image]

> The picture shows the data in table I have created partition based on Date, I like to retrieve data based on partition name, which is if partition name is 20170203 I am excepting results on that date.

Comment: can you share table data and expected output?

Comment: I have made an edit, check it once @HardikLeuwa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
where $partition.fpartfunction(date) = 1
```

This returns all the data in partition 1.

If you want to retrieve it from the date you can do as below,

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date(date) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES('2017-01-01','2018-01-01');
```

```
--first partition
SELECT *
FROM schema.table_name
WHERE key_column <= '2017-01-01';

--second partition
SELECT *
FROM schema.table_name
WHERE key_column > '2017-01-01' AND key_column <= '2018-01-01';

--last partition
SELECT *
FROM schema.table_name
WHERE key_column > '2018-01-01';
```

Comment: Is that SQL Server only?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may work for your need:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GetRowsWithinPartition (@InputDate DATE)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TV TABLE 
(StartDate DATE, 
EndDate DATE
)
INSERT INTO @TV (StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT TOP 1
CAST((CASE
    WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, @InputDate)) = 7 AND (DATEPART(DAY, @InputDate)) > 2
    THEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CONVERT(DATE, prv.Value, 116))
        WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, @InputDate)) > 7 AND (DATEPART(DAY, @InputDate)) >= 1
        THEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CONVERT(DATE, prv.Value, 116))
    ELSE prv.Value
    END) AS DATE) AS StartDate,
CAST((CASE
    WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, @InputDate)) = 7 AND (DATEPART(DAY, @InputDate)) > 2
    THEN prv.Value
        WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, @InputDate)) > 7 AND (DATEPART(DAY, @InputDate)) >= 1
        THEN prv.Value
    ELSE DATEADD(YEAR, 1, CONVERT(DATE, prv.Value, 116))
    END ) AS DATE) AS EndDate
FROM sys.partition_functions pf
INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes AS ps ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
INNER JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats pstats ON pstats.partition_number = dds.destination_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON p.partition_id = pstats.partition_id
INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds ON dds.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv ON pf.function_id = prv.function_id 
WHERE pstats.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTable')
GROUP BY prv.boundary_id, prv.value
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @InputDate, Convert(DATE, value, 116)))

SELECT yt.* FROM YourTable yt
INNER JOIN @TV t ON yt.DateColumn>=t.StartDate AND yt.DateColumn < t.EndDate
END

EXEC USP_GetRowsWithinPartition '2015-08-01'
```

Comment: Hi @KGRed if you don't mind can you elaborate about code shortly..

Comment: System views in JOINs for locating the exact partitions on a specific table (YourTable). -------
  
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @InputDate, Convert(DATE, value, 116))) and TOP 1 : 
For getting the nearest date from values in "value" column from [sys].[partition_range_values]. -------
  
CASE Statement: For getting Start and end dates of that particular range of partition which is a year in this case.  
  
July 3rd is taken Mid of year: when the input date falls in 2nd half of a year the top 1 value will be end date and vice versa. CASE statement is used to get Start & End Dates.

Answer (score 0):

(MySQL)

There is virtually no use for accessing a specific `PARTITION`.  You should let the `WHERE` clause pick which partition(s) to use.

Furthermore, there are very few uses for partitioning.  I recommend that you ignore that feature until you have a non-trivial amount of experience under your belt.

Any, to answer your question...  Yes, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME  PARTITION(partitionId);
```

But that was not available until 5.6.

The partitionid may need to be quoted, especially if it is a number.  For further research, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.